# Delete pickle file with python within Blender

Tags: python, scripting

Does anyone know if it's possible to delete a pickle file with python in Blender please ?

I need to store some data to use them later. I've created a pickle file to store them (so, maybe is not the best way for that).

When I've finished my work, I need to delete the pickle file with an operator after having restored my data saved in the pickle file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard filesystem functions available in python can be used within blender.

```
import os
os.remove(path) # a single file
os.rmdir(path) # an empty folder
```

The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) include more info.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot for your answer.